# How to pass data to a child component from parent component when the child component is being called through router-outlet?

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I am a beginner. I could not find any way. I tried using Behavior subject which I created in a service that I created. The behaviorSubject gets its next value from the parent component (this.service.behaviorsub.next(value to pass to child))

The service.behaviorsub is then called in the child component, where I used subscribe to get the data. But I get undefined, when I try to console.log that data.

Either there could be a better way to pass data from parent to child( which is called through router-outlet), or there could be better way to use behaviorSubject.

Thanks in advance!

Code sample:
->parent
html

```
    <div class="container" *ngIf="outlet.isActivated == false">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col" *ngFor="let item of items">
         <app-another-component [Item]="item" (click)="should-take-to-another- 
     component-for-which-there-is-router-outlet()"></app-another-component>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
     <router-outlet  #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
   </div>
```

app-another-component has certain details such as title and image, clicking on which should open another component with that particular title and image only (and this title does not appear as query params).

For behaviorsubject:
In service file:

```
behavior: new BehaviorSubject<type>(value);
```

In parent file:

```
should-take-to-another-component-for-which-there-is-router-outlet(data:type){
this.service.behavior.next(data);
}
```

In file( which is grandchild, but through routing, it opens this file only)

```
ngOnInIt(){
 this.service.behavior.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data)
}
```

Here the logged data shows undefined

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Code sample pls

Comment: using BehaviourSubject is a good approach can you post code related to that as well

Comment: you can check resolvers in angular routing, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the rare case like that, you could use a provider that resides lives in the parent component.
When using the @Component decorator, you can initialize a provider (which uses @Injectable decorator), that you can also inject into your component that is sent in the router outlet.

Then you can setup an observable that your parent listens to, which could be a behaviorsubject.

A very simple example:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyOutputter {

private thelistener$ = new BehaviorSubject<TheDataObjectYouWant>(null);

get listener$() {
return this.thelistener$.asObservable();
}

setTheOutputValue (value: TheDataObjectYouWant) { // or use a setter. I prefer a method, but this is more flavor imo.
this.thelistener$.next(value);
}

}
```

In your mother component (The one that contains the router outlet):

```
@Component({ // skipping template and styles and selector.
providers: [MyOutputter]
})
export class MotherComponent{

constructor(private myOutputter: MyOutputter) {
// setup listening and subscription of the getter here and do what you want it to do when receiving
}

}
```

In the component that is used in the output

```
@Component({}) // skipping the template and stuff
export class ChildOutputComponent {

constructor(private outputter: MyOutputter) {}

// use this.outputter.setTheOutputValue() wherever you need to send the output.

}
```

This is one way of dealing with this. It's not perfect, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried this, but this does not work. When I next() the behavior subject in the parent component, and then subscribe to it in the grandchild component, the console.log gives undefined data. Although, if I try to next() the behaviorSubject in the grandchild itself, I am able to console.log() the data.

Comment: Could you show a stackblitz of how you did this? Easier to see what is wrong.

Comment: Take a look at this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crls4x

You can ignore the second output. The problem with the stackblitz as it stands now is that I have the appcomponent inside the router as well as it being bootstrapped. The bootstrapped AppComponent has it's own provider, but that provider instance isn't connected to the other components. The second that is in the router is however connected to the child and grandchild.

The main point was to illustrate that you can use a provider to get the data that way.